# How to check if array element is the only one of its value in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've seen many similar questions and answers here but none that directly answered this question. For each array element I'm looking for a way (with JavaScript) to check if it's the only one of its kind in the array, or if there is at least one other of it. For example:

```
const arr = [1,2,2]
```

looking for something that will return

```
true, false, false
```

when looping through arr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 2];
console.log(arr.map(item => arr.indexOf(item) === arr.lastIndexOf(item)));
```

```
const arr = [1, 2, 2];
arr.map(item => arr.indexOf(item) === arr.lastIndexOf(item));
```

Comment: Careful: runs in O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two passes:

- build a `Map` containing the count of each element
- look up each element in that `Map`

Like so:

```
const getCounts = iterable => {
    const counts = new Map();

    for (const x of iterable) {
        counts.set(x, (counts.get(x) ?? 0) + 1);  // use || for ES6 compat
    }

    return counts;
};

const arrCounts = getCounts(arr);
arr.map(x => arrCounts.get(x) === 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the time complexity of doing it this way?

Comment: @Tzvi2: In practice, linear, although I think the JS spec allows it to be O(n log n) (e.g. BST-based `Map` implementations).

Comment: the `...counts.get(x) ?? 0) +1);` checks if x is in counts and if not sets it as zero, if yes adds one to existing val?

Comment: `counts.get(x)` is `undefined` when `x` is not in `counts`, so `counts.get(x) ?? 0` is 0 for a new entry and the existing count otherwise. That `+ 1` increments the count. So yes, what you said, but one instead of zero.